# What do names with blue backings represent in chat?

Tags: eve-online

I have noticed since logging in after the Retribution 1.1 patch that in certain zones there are a large number of players with their names on a blue background appearing in chat, as below;

[image]

What does the styling applied to these names represent?

Is this a new feature that was added in the Retribution 1.1 patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are DUST bunnies. Dust 514 players are in the same universe as EVE players, and are shown in local chat with the blue background you observed.

Take a look at [this dev blog](http://community.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=73468) for more details about this.

Comment: "dust bunnies"? Is that an official name or a colloquialism?

Comment: CCP Karkur called them that in the dev blog. It's not the official name, but it seems CCP uses it sometimes.

Comment: Are these players able to see anything we say in chat in EVE?

Comment: They see the same local chat as EVE players do, as far as I understand it.